# Issues with Rust timelines and ownerships

Tags: rust, lifetime, ownership

I am trying to create a hashmap by reading a file. Below is the code that I have written. The twist is that I need to persist `subset_description` till the next iteration so that I can store it in the hasmap and then finally return the hashmap.

```rust
fn myfunction(filename: &Path) -> io::Result<HashMap<&str, &str>> {
    let mut SIF = HashMap::new();
    let file = File::open(filename).unwrap();
    let mut subset_description = "";
    for line in BufReader::new(file).lines() {
        let thisline = line?;
        let line_split: Vec<&str> = thisline.split("=").collect();
        subset_description = if thisline.starts_with("a") {
            let subset_description = line_split[1].trim();
            subset_description
        } else {
            ""
        };
        let subset_ids = if thisline.starts_with("b") {
            let subset_ids = line_split[1].split(",");
            let subset_ids = subset_ids.map(|s| s.trim());
            subset_ids.collect()
        } else {
            Vec::new()
        };
        for k in subset_ids {
            SIF.insert(k, subset_description);
            println!("");
        }
        if thisline.starts_with("!dataset_table_begin") {
            break;
        }
    }
    Ok(SIF)
}
```

I am getting the below error and not able to resolve this

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `thisline`
  --> src/main.rs:73:5
   |
51 |         let line_split: Vec<&str> = thisline.split("=").collect();
   |                                     -------- `thisline` is borrowed here
...
73 |     Ok(SIF)
   |     ^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies within the guarantees the Rust makes on your behalf. The root of the problem can be seen as following. You are reading a file and manipulating it's content into a `HashMap`, and you are trying to return reference to the the data you read. But by returning a reference you would need to guarantee, that the strings in the file wont be changed later on, which you naturally can not do.

In Rust terms you keep trying to return references to local variables, which get dropped at the end of the function, which would efficiently leave you with dangling pointers. Here is the changes I made, even though they may not be most efficient, they do compile.

```rust
fn myfunction(filename: &Path) -> io::Result<HashMap<String, String>> {
    let mut SIF = HashMap::new();
    let file = File::open(filename).unwrap();
    let mut subset_description = "";
    for line in BufReader::new(file).lines() {
        let thisline = line?;
        let line_split: Vec<String> = thisline.split("=").map(|s| s.to_string()).collect();
        subset_description = if thisline.starts_with("a") {
            let subset_description = line_split[1].trim();
            subset_description
        } else {
            ""
        };
        let subset_ids = if thisline.starts_with("b") {
            let subset_ids = line_split[1].split(",");
            let subset_ids = subset_ids.map(|s| s.trim());
            subset_ids.map(|s| s.to_string()).collect()
        } else {
            Vec::new()
        };
        for k in subset_ids {
            SIF.insert(k, subset_description.to_string());
            println!("");
        }
        if thisline.starts_with("!dataset_table_begin") {
            break;
        }
    }
    Ok(SIF)
}
```

As you can see, now you give away the ownership of strings in return value. This is achieved by modifying the return type and using `to_string()` function, to give away the ownership of local strings to `HashMap`.

There is an argument that `to_string()` is slow, so you can explore the use of into or `to_owned()`, but as I am not proficient with those constructs I can not assist you in optimization.